# Which test should I use for this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have two groups (A and B), observed on day 0 and day 7.

On each group there are 10 observations. So 2 x 2 x 10 = 40 results on my dataset.

I want to find out if the control factor between group A and B had any effects over the week.

Which statistical test should I use ?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs covers this design

Answer (score 0):

The repeated measures design (also known as a within-subjects design) uses the same subjects with every condition of the research, including the control. You can try with a RM ANOVA (?)